# How much performance do I lose by increasing the number of trips to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, code-maintainability

I have a web application where the web server and SQL Server 2008 database sit on different boxes in the same server farm.

**If I take a monolithic stored procedure and break it up into several smaller stored procs, thus making the client code responsible for calls to multiple stored procedures instead of just one, and I going to notice a significant performance hit in my web application?**

---

Additional Background Info:

I have a stored procedure with several hundred lines of code containing decision logic, update statements, and finally a select statement that returns a set of data to the client.

I need to insert a piece of functionality into my client code (in this sense, the client code is the ASP web server that is calling the database server) that calls a component DLL.  However, the stored procedure is updating a recordset and returning the udpated data in the same call, and my code ideally needs to be called *after* the decision logic and update statements are called, but *before* the data is returned to the client.

To get this functionality to work, I'm probably going to have to split the existing stored proc into at least two parts: one stored proc that updates the database and another that retrieves data from the database.  I would then insert my new code between these stored proc calls.

When I look at this problem, I can't help but think that, from a code maintenance point of view, it would be much better to isolate *all* of my update and select statements into thin stored procs and leave the business logic to the client code.  That way whenever I need to insert functionality or decision logic into my client code, all I need to do is change the client code instead of modifying a huge stored proc.

Although using thin stored procs might be better from a code maintenance point-of-view, how much performance pain will I experience by increasing the number of trips to the database?  The net result to the data is the same, but I'm touching the database more frequently.  How does this approach affect performance when the application is scaled up to handle demand?

I'm not one to place performance optimization above everything else, especially when it affects code maintenance, but I don't want to shoot myself in the foot and create headaches when the web application has to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, as a rule of thumb you should make roundtrips to SQL server at a minimum.

the "hit" on the server is very expensive, it's actually more expensive to devide the same operation into 3 parts then doing 1 hit and everything else on the server.

regarding maintenance, you can call 1 stored proc from the client, having that proc call another 2 proc's.

I had an application with extreme search logic, thats what I did to implement it.

some benchmarking results...
I had a client a while back that had servers falling and crumbling down, when we checked for the problem it was many roundtrips to SQL server, when we minimized it, the servers got back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

It will affect it. We use a Weblogic server where all the business logic is in the AppServer connected to a DB/2 database. We mostly use entity beans in our project and for most business service calls make several trips to the DB with no visible side effects. (We do tune some queries to be multi-table when needed).

It really depends on your app. You are going to need to benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

A well setup SQL Server on good hardware can process many thousands of transactions per second.

In fact breaking up a large stored procedure can be beneficial, because you can only have one cached query plan per batch. Breaking into several batches means they will each get their own query plan.

You should definitely err on the side of code-maintenance, but benchmark to be sure.

Given that the query plan landscape will chnage, you should alos be prepared to update your indexes, perhaps creating different covering indexes.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, this question is closely related to tight vs. loose coupling.

At the outset: You could always take the monolithic stored procedure and break it up into several smaller stored procs, **that are all called by one stored procedure**, thus making the client code only responsible for calling one stored procedure.

Unless the client will do something (change the data or provide status to user) I would probably not recommend moving multiple calls to the client, since you would be more tightly coupling the client to the order of operations for the stored procedure without a significant performance increase.

Either way, I would benchmark it and adjust from there.